# (PowerShell Studio 2014 Trial) Incomplete output in textbox

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-studio

I created a form using PowerShell Studio 2014 Trial with two controls i.e. a command button & a text button. Below is the code for click event on button1-

```
$button1_Click={

$results=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = "application"; StartTime = "10/30/2014 12:00:01 AM"; EndTime = "10/30/2014 11:59:59 PM" }

$textbox1.Text=$results
}
```

When I execute this, it does not give the expected output containing logs.

It displays- `"System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord"`

[image: Form]

However, if I run-

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = "application"; StartTime = "10/30/2014 12:00:01 AM"; EndTime = "10/30/2014 11:59:59 PM" }
```

on PowerShell ISE, it shows all logs.

Comment: It is outputting what you are asking it to do which is the object `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord` PowerShell console handles object output better with cmdlets like `Format-Default`. What do you want in the textbox? All of that information? Then you would need to format it as a string first.

Comment: @Matt- Yes, I want all that information. How do I format it as a string? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment your getting the output you requested. PowerShell console handles object output with built-in cmdlets like `Out-Default`. You said you wanted *all that information* but I'm guessing you wanted what was display by default. Therefore I would make results the following

```
$results = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = "application"; StartTime = "10/30/2014 12:00:01 AM"; EndTime = "10/30/2014 11:59:59 PM" } | Select provider,timecreated,id,leveldisplayname,message | Format-Table | Out-String -Width 1024
```

Use `Select` to get only what we want. Change this as you see fit. Use Format-Table to make fixed width output then pipe it into `Out-String`

Comment: @Matt- How can I format the data. As of now it is coming as - http://s27.postimg.org/vei7njmab/display_submit.png
I want it to look properly formatted as in proper column wise (like it comes in PowerShell ISE).

Comment: @SanchitRasiya that is happeneing since PowerShell is using a fixed width font like Courier. Change the font of your text box to a fixed width one and you will be fine.

Comment: @Matt- I tried changing the font to Lucida Console. It looks a bit good. Check- http://postimg.org/image/zeopudzw3/ How can I increase the size of column so that I can see full value of TimeCreated? It is trimming the time value.

Comment: @SanchitRasiya try playing with the `-Width` of `Out-String`. Please remember that if you have other questions please either search SO for solutions or post new questions. Thanks